# How do I install libXcursor.so.1 on Debian?

Tags: debian

I have a Debian 7.3 vps, where I'm trying to run a Unity3d server. I get the error

> `error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory`

`apt-cache search` finds nothing, searching google I've noticed it might be somehow related to `ia32-libs`, but if I try to install that I get

> `ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386 but it is not installable`

I'm stuck, what am I supposed to do to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite simply, the package `libxcursor1` contains it.

Comment: I already had this package, but 64 bit and a 32 bit game wasn't seeing it.  `sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386` helped.